# React Redux - Why mapStateToProps is called before constructor?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Two questions:

1. Why `mapStateToProps` is called before constructor?
2. As a side-effect of 1

   `constructor (props) {
        base(props)
        // props already have values from "mapStateToTprops"
    }`

why that is being done automagically?

3. Not every `mapStateToProps` invokes `ComponentWillReceiveProps` (this is the case when it loads first time) See this link [enter link description here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html)

#### Update 1

If I want to write a condition like:

`if (props.isAuthenticated) { 
     browserHistory.push("/admin/dashboard")
 }`

Which method will be most suitable to hook. Keep in mind that I want to enforce this condition on each state change (because according to **leo's** answer ComponentWillReceiveProps is not reliable)?

Comment: Well that's the purpose of `mapStateToProps` to send props to component, so it's expected behavior, I suppose.

Comment: Yes but it skips the `ComponentWillReceiveProps` I expected it to first hit `constructor` then the `ComponentWillReceiveProps` where I decide upon what to do with those props

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is not called magically before your constructor. It is done by [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/ea53d6fb076359a864a1d543568d951d4b3eab3d/src/components/connect.js) which is a [Higher Order Component](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.nho2ygep2) that executes `mapStateToProps` before your component is initialised. In fact, `connect` initialises your component in its body.

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent)
```

---

Why `componentWillReceiveProps` not executed? Because React doesn't call `componentWillReceiveProps` for the initial render, so you should use `componentDidMount` instead.

[componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops)

> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.

Comment: Why then `ComponentWillReceiveProps` is not being called?

Comment: That said, If I want to write a condition like `if (props.isAuthenticated)  { browserHistory.push("/admin/dashboard")} `. Which method will be most suitable to hook. Keep in mind that I wan't to enforce this condition on each state change.

Comment: componentWillMount (initial render) + componentWillReceiveProps (after that) in my opinion

Comment: From the docs regarding "ComponentWillReceiveProps": Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.

Comment: @leo Thanks for your response! P.S. Does that mean there will be duplication?

Comment: no, you wrap if (props.isAuthenticated) { browserHistory.push("/admin/dashboard")} into a function and call it from the two lifecycles. They are mutually exclusive. BTW: componentDidMount is actually better than componentWillMount because it is used for side effects.

Comment: @leo Perfect thank you very much. Your answer cleared down a lot of misunderstandings.